# New list item Error

Tags: sharepoint-online, list

When I create a new list item on a list we have used hundreds of times in the past I now get an error that says "Sorry, we didn't find that app" any ideas what could be causing this?

This is a list with a flow connected to it in SharePoint online.

The sharePoint request failed with error: '404 FILE NOT FOUND'.

Comment: What action are you using in the Flow?

Comment: Please give more detail about how the new item is created and take a screenshot of the error. Are you starting in the list view? Or on a page with a list web part? Is the list using PowerApps or some other custom form?  What is the purpose of the Flow? Is the flow creating the list item? Or does the flow run after the list item has been created?  Please edit your question and then post a comment to alert people following this question.

Comment: flow for some odd reason was hung up, had to enable and re enable it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be something wrong with the flow. Can you explain a little about the process of the flow?

A few things you can check:

1. Make sure you have enough privilege on this list and the flow. Test again with a global admin account.
2. Try turning the flow off and then create a new item in the list again.
3. Test in another list with a similar flow attached and see if you can reproduce this issue.